# httpContextAccessor.HttpContext иногда null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

Есть проект на  ASP .Net Core 2.2

Один из методов контроллера использует сервис `SomeService`, который получает по средством DI. Мне нужно получить контекст запроса через `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor`, и я его подключаю через конструктор(в примере ниже) в сервисе.

Подключаю я его через `Startup.cs` вот так:

```cs
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

В результате при использовании я не всегда имею контекст запроса, Почему?

```cs
public class SomeService: ISomeService{    
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public SomeService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    private async Task Method() {
        if(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext == null) {
            /// <---------- WTF?
        } else {
            /// Тут что то делаю с контекстом запроса
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: потому что у вас не всегда вызывается метод `BuyProjectTasksService`

Comment: @tCode Это опечатка, благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт. Прошу меня извинить. Я не обратил внимание на то что я пытался это сделать в асинхронном методе, не дожидаясь его завершения выходил из него. :)

Comment: Ну почему же, хороший вопрос. Я сам так полчаса тупил, пока не проверил еще раз async/await.